# How to show the status bar in the iOS simulator?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Currently, the status bar is not showing up in my iOS emulator.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?  It shows up on my storyboard but not when I run the simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to Your code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

And **don't use** this, because it's **deprecated**:

<strike>`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];`</strike>

Comment: Thanks...Why on earth would I need to add that...Shouldn't it be the default?

Comment: While you're at it, do you know why my custom added toolbar appears in the simulator but disappears in the storyboard whenever I add a tab bar controller to it?

Comment: @Nosrettap It should be by default `YES`, but I think in Your case is somehow set to `NO`. So I'm suggesting this. I can't understand Your question correctly.

Comment: Its a new question, but I have a starboard of the form, NavigationViewController > TabbedViewController >> ViewControllerA...Where I added a custom toolbar to the top of ViewControllerA.  It works fine in the simulator but I cannot see it in the storyboard...There is just a blank space where it should be...More curiously, if I delete the tabbed controller, it shows up fine in the storyboard

Comment: Here's my actual question, if you want to take a stab at answering it.  Note that I'm pretty new to Xcode and iOS programming so its likely some very simple, stupid problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618410/toolbars-in-xcode-storyboard-disappearing

Comment: @Nosrettap Ok, I'll take a look.

Comment: I just had the exact same thing happen to me in the latest XCode release [Version 6.2 (6C131e)] ... I tried everything including adjusting things in the Info.plist, LaunchScreen.xib and Main.storyboard files ... adding the "setStatusBarHidden" call to "AppDelegate.m's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method Did solve it ... thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

If it's a problem with the simulator itself you can always try **iOS Simulator » Reset Content and Settings…**. If it is in your app try

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Simon's answer make sure in your Info.plist that if you have the "Status bar is initially hidden" it is set to "NO" if you don't see a row with this text that just means it's the default, "NO". My guess is it's likely just the simulator, as it's a bit hard to add the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];` line into your code by mistake. Follow Simon's answer to reset the iOS Simulator if that doesn't work check try checking your Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to manipulate the status bar both programmatically and through configuration. As other answers have stated, you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

If you prefer a consistent configuration for your application, you can modify your app's info.plist. It's likely that you aren't seeing the status bar because your Info plist is configured to hide it.

You can add an entry in the Info plist for **Status bar is initially hidden** with a Boolean value of YES or NO. Additionally, you can customize the look of the status bar in the Info plist through the **Status bar style** key.